# Prove $GL_2(R)/S$ is isomorphic to $Z_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing, group-isomorphism

I'm asked to show that $GL_2(\mathbb{R})/S$ is isomorphic to $Z_2$ where

$GL_2(\mathbb{R})=$$\left\{A=
 \begin{pmatrix}
  a & b\\ 
  c & d
\end{pmatrix}, |a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R} , det A \neq 0 \right\}$

$S=$$\left\{A \in GL_2(\mathbb{R}) |a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R} , det A > 0 \right\}$

$Z_2$ is the additive group of residue class module 2

I have proved S is a normal subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ but can't find a mapping to prove $GL_2(\mathbb{R})/S$ is isomorphic to $Z_2$

Comment: Sorry, I have edited

Comment: You can still edit the title.

Comment: Do you have the cosets of $S$?